# XSLT/Xpath - combining multiple axes in a single statement to find a "grand nephew"?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document, and I need to locate the nearest descendant (physically closest in the tree - "treasure" in the example) to my previous-sibling.  I don't know any element names, element contents, nor how deep the current node or the node I want to select are in the document.  An example follows:

```
<tagA>
    <tagB>
        <tagC>
             junk
        </tagC>
        <tagC>
            <tagD>
                 junk
            </tagD>
        </tagC>
    </tagB>
    <tagB>
        <tagC>
            treasure
        </tagC>
    </tagB>
</tagA>
<tagX/>
```

From the position of tagX, I need to be able to test if my preceding sibling has descendants and select the closest one, "Treasure".

I'm guessing I can use `descendant::*[last()]` once I have the preceding sibling selected, but I'm not sure of the syntax to get there.  Obviously `previous-sibling::descendant::*[last()]` won't work.

Is there a way to combine these axes to achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had only minor mistakes in your XPath expression.
Try the following expression from the context node `<tagX>`.

```
preceding-sibling::*[1]/descendant::*[last()]
```

Its output is

```
<tagC>
    treasure
</tagC>
```

If you only need the text content, append `/text()` to the expression.

---

An alternative expression is

```
(preceding-sibling::*[1]//text()[normalize-space()])[last()]/..
```

The output using the sample XML is the same.
You have to decide which solution does better fit your needs.

Comment: I would suggest `(preceding-sibling::*[1]//text())[last()]` - mind you, `preceding-sibling::*` selects *all* those siblings, not only the immediate one.

Comment: @Tomalak: That could be even better, but it would select the last `text()` node and not the last `element()`.

Comment: You can always add `/..` to go up from the text node to the container element if necessary.

Comment: Although `[text()]` should probably be `[text()[normalize-space()]]`, in order to catch the non-empty text nodes only.

Comment: @Tomalak: I added the solution as an alternative to my solution.

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat, as they say. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that makes a lot more sense!